# Cooldown on Post in PHP

Tags: php, post, input

*I have a really basic PHP chat system. Only thing post do is adding a line with $user and $message to log.html.*

But users can spam with holding **enter** or pressing **enter** multiple times. And that causes lag in website.

I want to make a cooldown system for like 0.3 seconds. **If it's in cooldown, don't let user post or disable the input for 0.3 seconds.**

How can I make this?

---

Here, my code :

**index.php** contains 2 things. "log.html" and these codes

```
    <form name="message" action="">
        <div class="input-group dropup" id="bottom">
  <input type="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" maxlength="65" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message here.">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name"submitmsg" id="submitmsg">Send</button>
  </span>
</div>
</form>
```

And the post.php contains these codes

```
<?
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){

$text = $_POST['text'];

$sp = fopen("player_log.html", 'a');
fwrite($sp, "<div class='msgln'>[" .date("Y-m-d"). "-".date("g:i A"). " | " .$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."] <b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>: ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");
fclose($sp);

// SOME str_replace CODES FOR EMOTICONS, BANNED TEXTS ETC..

$fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln' style='color: #BDBDBD;'><b style='color: #FFBF00;'>[Player]&nbsp;".$_SESSION['name'].":</b> ".$finaltext."<br></div>");
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the setTimeout() function in JavaScript. When enter is pressed, disable the user from entering another message (I can't comment on how to do this, as you have posted none of your code). Then use the setTimeout() function to enable the input after x amount of seconds (below shows an alert after 3 seconds):

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    alert("Hello"); 
}, 3000);
```

If you want more help, expand on your question and show us some code.

Having read through the code you have posted, it could be worth doing what others have suggested - check if the content is empty and don't post it. However, this still won't stop users spamming with one letter replies. If you want to users from quickly entering messages and posting them, I believe the timeout would work best. If you want to only stop users from holding down enter, checking for empty messages would probably be better. The best solution (in my eyes) would be to use both techniques as it would stop users from quickly spamming and stop users just entering blank messages.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try. By the way, I added my codes.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the input is not a good solution. It will disrupt the user experience and users gonna hate you for that.

A better approach would be to do nothing if the message is empty or contains spaces or banned characters only.

Comment: From personal experience most users won't notice anything up to a 5 second pause where they can't enter another message. Since Eren only wants to pause to stop for under a second, the majority of users won't notice (can you type something and press enter under 1 second?)

Comment: What do you think about an OK + Enter? :) Also, most chatters (myself included) start typing quickly again if forgot something. Hindering the user in any way is never a good idea.

Comment: I also often type after forgetting something. But I don't think the user wants to disable people from typing but just from submitting what they have typed.

Comment: This one is a very good idea. Regarding spamming: if this is a chat system it would require authentication for every message sent, so spamming would be unlikely to happen (unless it is a completely open system)

Comment: As he said it's a basic system, I doubt it does :)

Answer (score 0):

When your Users enters a message and you recieve it, just add a timestamp to a session variable. When the User sends a message again, check the timestamp in the session, with the current timestamp.
http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
```

To this

```
$text = $_POST['text'] || exit();
```

This way if a user posts nothing, nothing happens.